# How can i use SUM function with OVER clause having same values in order by column to return correct sum?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have a scenario where I need to get the sum column using sql SUM function. I have a sample data like this:

Sample table:

```
dateCol,   myCol
-----------------------
'12:00:01'   3
'12:00:01'   4
'12:00:01'   5
'12:00:01'  NULL
'12:00:01'  NULL
'12:00:01'   3
```

I'm using the query shown below to get sum over myCol column

```
select 
    dateCol, myCol,
    sum(case when dateCol is not null  then 1 end) over (order by dateCol) as sumCol
from   
    sampleTable;
```

I get these results:

```
    dateCol myCol   sumCol
--------------------------
1   12:00:01    3       4
2   12:00:01    4       4
3   12:00:01    5       4
4   12:00:01    NULL    4
5   12:00:01    NULL    4
6   12:00:01    3       4
```

but I expect these results:

```
    dateCol myCol   sumCol
--------------------------
1   12:00:01    3       1
2   12:00:01    4       2
3   12:00:01    5       3
4   12:00:01    NULL    3
5   12:00:01    NULL    3
6   12:00:01    3       4
```

How can I modify the query to return the expected result?

Comment: As `dateCol` contains the same date for the rows you are showing, `order by dateCol` results in an arbitrary order. Your running total can even be in another order than the order of the result rows (which would even be the case were the dates distinct, as your query lacks an `ORDER BY` clause). You need an additional column for sorting or create one with `ROW_NUMBER` to get started.

Answer (score 1):

The default in SQL for cumulative sums is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, not `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.  You seem to have no way to distinguish the rows.

You can try an explicit window specification:

```
select dateCol, myCol,
       count(dateCol) over (order by dateCol rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as sumCol
from sampleTable;
```

Notice that I also simplified the logic, using `count()` instead of `sum()`.

If you have a column to specify the ordering, then use that column in the `order by`:

```
select dateCol, myCol,
       count(dateCol) over (order by dateCol, ?) as sumCol
from sampleTable;
```

That will make the sort stable and distinguish the rows.

Absent that, you can create a column.  But, the results may be in a different order -- SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So:

```
select dateCol, myCol,
       count(dateCol) over (order by dateCol, seqnum) as sumCol
from (select st.*, row_number() over (order by dateCol) as seqnum
      from sampleTable
     ) st;
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain using standard SQL. You are trying to group dateCol, myCol with agregate function sum. Basically you need to define GROUP BY clause, and result view can be sorted using ordinary order by clause

```
  select dateCol, myCol,
         sum(case when dateCol is not null  then 1 else 0 end)  as sumCol
  from sampleTable
  group by dateCol, myCol
  order by dateCol
```